# Pandas read_csv not splitting columns according to the separator

Tags: python, pandas

I have data from John Hopkins Github.
https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series

I want to import the data using the following command:

```
data = pd.read_csv('JohnHopkins.csv', sep=',')
```

However it is not possible for me to seperate the columns.

```
Province/State,Country/Region,Lat,Long,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20,1/25/20,1/26/20,1/27/20,1/28/20,1/29/20,1/30/20,1/31/20,2/1/20,2/2/20,2/3/20,2/4/20,2/5/20,2/6/20,2/7/20,2/8/20,2/9/20,2/10/20,2/11/20,2/12/20,2/13/20,2/14/20,2/15/20,2/16/20,2/17/20,2/18/20,2/19/20,2/20/20,2/21/20,2/22/20,2/23/20,2/24/20,2/25/20,2/26/20,2/27/20,2/28/20,2/29/20,3/1/20,3/2/20,3/3/20,3/4/20,3/5/20,3/6/20,3/7/20,3/8/20,3/9/20,3/10/20,3/11/20,3/12/20,3/13/20,3/14/20,3/15/20,3/16/20,3/17/20,3/18/20,3/19/20,3/20/20,3/21/20,3/22/20,3/23/20,3/24/20,3/25/20,3/26/20,3/27/20,3/28/20,3/29/20,3/30/20,3/31/20,4/1/20,4/2/20,4/3/20,4/4/20,4/5/20,4/6/20,4/7/20,4/8/20,4/9/20,4/10/20,4/11/20,4/12/20,4/13/20,4/14/20,4/15/20,4/16/20,4/17/20,4/18/20,4/19/20,4/20/20,4/21/20,4/22/20,4/23/20,4/24/20,4/25/20,4/26/20,4/27/20,4/28/20,4/29/20,4/30/20,5/1/20,5/2/20,5/3/20,5/4/20,5/5/20,5/6/20,5/7/20,5/8/20,5/9/20,5/10/20,5/11/20,5/12/20,5/13/20,5/14/20,5/15/20,5/16/20,5/17/20,5/18/20,5/19/20,5/20/20,5/21/20,5/22/20,5/23/20,5/24/20,5/25/20,5/26/20,5/27/20,5/28/20,5/29/20,5/30/20,5/31/20,6/1/20,6/2/20,6/3/20,6/4/20,6/5/20,6/6/20,6/7/20,6/8/20,6/9/20,6/10/20,6/11/20,6/12/20,6/13/20,6/14/20,6/15/20,6/16/20,6/17/20,6/18/20,6/19/20,6/20/20,6/21/20,6/22/20,6/23/20,6/24/20,6/25/20,6/26/20,6/27/20,6/28/20,6/29/20,6/30/20,7/1/20,7/2/20,7/3/20,7/4/20,7/5/20,7/6/20,7/7/20,7/8/20,7/9/20,7/10/20,7/11/20,7/12/20,7/13/20,7/14/20,7/15/20,7/16/20,7/17/20,7/18/20,7/19/20,7/20/20,7/21/20,7/22/20,7/23/20,7/24/20,7/25/20,7/26/20,7/27/20,7/28/20,7/29/20,7/30/20,7/31/20,8/1/20,8/2/20,8/3/20,8/4/20,8/5/20,8/6/20,8/7/20,8/8/20,8/9/20,8/10/20,8/11/20,8/12/20,8/13/20,8/14/20,8/15/20,8/16/20,8/17/20,8/18/20,8/19/20,8/20/20,8/21/20,8/22/20,8/23/20,8/24/20,8/25/20,8/26/20,8/27/20,8/28/20,8/29/20,8/30/20,8/31/20,9/1/20,9/2/20,9/3/20,9/4/20,9/5/20,9/6/20,9/7/20,9/8/20,9/9/20,9/10/20,9/11/20,9/12/20,9/13/20
0   ,Afghanistan,33.93911,67.709953,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...
1   ,Albania,41.1533,20.1683,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0...
2   ,Algeria,28.0339,1.6596,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...
3   ,Andorra,42.5063,1.5218,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...
4   ,Angola,-11.2027,17.8739,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0...
```

Do you know a workaround?

Comment: Can you link the csv file, I can't find in the Github repo you provided

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the issue. Here I'm importing directly the raw csv file from the github link the OP provided.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv", sep=",")


   ## df.head()
   ##  Out[61]: 
   ##    Province/State Country/Region       Lat       Long  1/22/20  1/23/20  1/24/20  ...  9/7/20  9/8/20  9/9/20  9/10/20  9/11/20  9/12/20  9/13/20
   ##  0            NaN    Afghanistan  33.93911  67.709953        0        0        0  ...   38494   38520   38544    38572    38606    38641    38716
   ##  1            NaN        Albania  41.15330  20.168300        0        0        0  ...   10406   10553   10704    10860    11021    11185    11353
   ##  2            NaN        Algeria  28.03390   1.659600        0        0        0  ...   46653   46938   47216    47488    47752    48007    48254
   ##  3            NaN        Andorra  42.50630   1.521800        0        0        0  ...    1261    1261    1301     1301     1344     1344     1344
   ##  4            NaN         Angola -11.20270  17.873900        0        0        0  ...    2981    3033    3092     3217     3279     3335     3388

   ##  [5 rows x 240 columns]
```